# Executing function in Google Scripts API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to executing a function in the Google Scripts API. As a test, I'm using the Logger function:

```
function myFunction() {
    Logger.log('The function executed');
 }
```

When I then click on the Run Function button in the API, the logger didn't seem to write the text.

What am I missing? Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I ran this from the Script Editor and it worked.  Is it possible you have 2 functions with the same name?  If so, rename this one and try it then.

Comment: Thanks: this seemed to work!